# Do humans differ from other animals by being able to push and pop memory?

Tags: psycholinguistics, computer-science, chomsky-hierarchy

The Chomsky hierarchy of types 0,1,2,3 grammars correspond, as he showed, to the abstract automata classified in accordance with their use of memory.  The type 2 grammars, the context free phrase structure grammars, are computationally equivalent to the push-down store automata (which Chomsky was the first to characterize), which use memory as a push-down stack.  Stacks are the mechanism by which computer programs call subroutines. The push-down stack is accessed by push and pop instructions, which store and retrieve memories on the stack.

The fact that a push-down stack is in use explains why both human languages and modern high-level programming languages have hierarchical tree structures, since the items below a node in a tree structure correspond to a subroutine in programming.

Yet, so far as I know, nothing neurological corresponding to memory pushes and pops has been discovered by brain scientists.  This is a puzzle.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Entering subroutines (and, importantly, then continuing execution of the outer routine) happens in tasks outside language, and other animals do it too, right?  For example, creating or just finding a tool for a task.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer How is finding a tool for a task like a subroutine?  Are the skills involved generalized to other tasks for, say, monkeys?  Or octopuses?

Comment: My suggestion is that "computational equivalence" does not tell you what actual cognitive status is. But furthermore, brain scientists have yet to discover anything probative about the physical nature of language computation.

Comment: I did some searching around, and there [does appear to have been papers](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0749-596X(02)00515-6) suggesting that your push/pop metaphor may be applicable to sentence processing, as well as arguments against..

Comment: I would be more inclined, though, to look into studies of hierarchical chunking in animals as counterparts to phrase structure, which can also be explained through hierarchical chunking (see e.g. Bybee 2010, Diessel 2019). [Zebra finches](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5c0b/dcc02dc277da6e08fe77dcac77631d77c63e.pdf) appear to satisfy this, as they arrange syllables into chunks of syllables, and chunks of syllables into songs.

Comment: And [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1439-0310.2010.01772.x) finds evidence for statistical learning of chunkns in Bengalese finches, so they appear to use the same mechanisms that humans use to learn constituents/chunks as well.

Comment: @WavesWashSands I think you're missing the point that the crucial fact is humans have language and other animals don't.  So we seek some physiological explanation for this.  You can look for similarities between language and other animal communication systems until the cows come home, and it's not going to tell you why there is this difference.

Comment: @GregLee Sure, but your question was about humans being able to push and pop memory, and the evidence being used for this was hierarchical syntactic structure. So I think that if we can find hierarchical structure in animals that are acquired and processed using similar mechanisms, that would be evidence against your hypothesis.

Comment: @WavesWashSands "processed using similar mechanisms" means what?  Push and pop memory?  You're giving us zero evidence about that in other animals.  I never said or implied that hierarchical structure is diagnostic of push/pop memory.  Besides, showing that finches know something about breaking songs into phrases doesn't quite get us to hierarchical structure, does it?

Comment: @GregLee: If it's not hierarchical structure, then what is suggesting to you that push and pop memory is used in human language processing? Anyway, my argument is that if you can show that humans and animals both use the same mechanisms (chunking, statistical learning) to create hierarchical structures, then there is neither a need to suggest that push and pop memory is required, nor do we need to suggest human-specificity. Finch songs may show fewer 'layer's of hierarchy than what we see in humans from that paper, but it seems to me the difference with human language isn't qualitative.

Comment: @WavesWashSands, Context Free Grammar, in my view, is the most successful theory of human syntax we have.  CFG corresponds to push-down  automata with a  memory discipline using push/pop.  Hierarchical structure is a side-effect of generating expressions with a CFG. // If the difference between human and other animal systems isn't qualitative, what is it? Quantitative?  Quantity of what?  Brain matter?  Chomsky and Lenneberg argued against this view much better than I can.  I refer you to them.

Comment: Specifically, for a summary, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Lenneberg

Comment: Then I think, echoing @user6726's comment, that this argument seems to be mistaking the map for the territory. Even if CFGs were the most satisfying models we have for the phenomenological description of syntax, (I'd say we have better ones...), it doesn't follow that they are cognitively plausibly represented in the brain, so it's not really an argument for push and pop memory. // I was talking about the number of layers in the hierarchy. I wasn't making a claim about human language in general (although I do think it's plausible that there's no qualitative difference.)

Comment: @WavesWashSands I have no idea what "phenomenological description of syntax" means.

Comment: @WavesWashSands Do these better models explain why there is a Coordinate Structure Constraint with the across-the-board condition?  Because CFG does.  If that explanation is not known to you, just ask it as a question, and I'll answer it.

Comment: @GregLee: That explanation is not known to me, but why would we want to 'explain' a grammatical rule of English with CFGs or whatever other model of syntax we propose as a cognitive model? If the underlying idea is that the rule is universal, I'd respond that a rule being universal does not mean it should be built into the cognitive model (as opposed to obtaining it through learning), plus I know a handful of sentences in Classical Chinese which would be exceptions.

Comment: TBH, I think CFGs (and any other approaches that focus on building single parse trees) are neither adequate for describing syntax. Some linguistic problems are well known from Langacker's writings, but IMO the best argument is in Croft (2001); and the cognitive problems have been well argued by Bybee (2010), and much evidence accumulated since. (I'm not saying CFGs are never useful descriptively; they may well be useful for describing some phenomena in some languages, but I dispute their usefulness as a cognitive model, and its indiscriminate application to all languages and phenomena.)

Comment: @WavesWashSands Ross's CSC (Coordinate Structure Constraint) is not a rule.  It's a constraint on transformations.

Comment: This is all fair and well, until a longjmp is needed to escape the stack, which is modeled as a serial LIFO store (last in, first out), but is realized as random access storage in current implementations, and thus prone to manipulation and corruption. Really modern PLs try to prrvent this, but define stack only abstractly, if they want to be portable. Google's Dalvik VM is a register machine, in contrast, which is equivalent up to isomorphisms and thus can be compiled for from Java, that is frequently implemented as stack architechture (if I didn't mix that up). Just FYI.

Comment: And, if the stack just holds fixed size pointers, manipulating the code that it points to can be creatively abused to good effect, too, self mutating code is the highest art of assembly programming, if it comes to size compression (e.g. Duff's Device, or self extracting executables).

Comment: @vectory You paint a romantic picture of the brave (but lovable) rogue programmer who through a deep intuition sees a way to escape the suffocating regime of structured programming and unravels a puzzle with a daring strategically placed longjmp, which wins the day.

Comment: @GregLee: Was that mostly an FYI, or is it relevant to my response to your argument? Because I'm really not sure ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you know more about this than I do, but problems like [center embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_embedding) make me question whether push/pop memory is a useful abstraction for human brain.  Quoting Wikipedia:

> A man that a woman that a child that a bird that I heard saw knows loves.

If human brains actually possessed unlimited (or even reasonably limited) push/pop memory, we would have no problem parsing this.  The fact that we don't suggests, to me, that a human brain's capacity for "push/pop" operation is really limited.

Also, one must be careful when reasoning about mathematical models.  Push-down automata (PDA) are mathematically equivalent to CFG, loosely speaking, but it is not the only computational model that can recognize CFG.  For example, [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) can also parse all context-free languages, but its structure looks very different from a stack!

Comment: I agree that whether CFG is too powerful for modelling natural language is open to serious doubt.  Keeping this in mind, don't you have some reservations about recommending a still more powerful model?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean - I'm not a linguist and only have a passing familiarity with theory of computer languages.  Anyway, my personal  opinion (as layperson) is to heed: "All models are wrong, but some are useful."  A computational model can be still useful if it reflects some part of human languages well, even if it fails for the rest.

Comment: The class of pda, push-down store automata, is not a parsing algorithm, so I don't know how to compare it to the CYK algorithm.  Do you mean that  a computer executing the CYK algorithm does not use a push-down stack?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: As far as I understand, the set of languages that can be parsed by (vanilla) CYK algorithm is exactly the set of context-free languages.  As you can see from the wiki page, the algorithm doesn't really use a stack.  Of course, any modern computer executing the algorithm would use an execution stack, but then again such a computer will most likely also have a silicon-based random-access memory, and we don't consider "silicon-based RAM" an integral part of CYK algorithm.

Comment: Pda is not an algorithm! It's not a program or a class of programs.  It's a class of machines using the pd memory discipline (which is not random access memory).

Comment: there infix, postfix, prefix, outfix syntaxes for one level and many more alternations possible for multiple levels. You just picked an idiosyncratic order, but used a correct one later in your text. Where is the difference? Also, I do have problems parsing it, but because it's unusual, yet I wouldn't argue it were ungrammatical in any other way.